# most of the time VERSUS for the most time

Tags: adjectives

> While living in the States I lived in different places, most of the
> time I lived in LA, but for the most time I lived in NY.

I can't put my finger on the difference between "most of the time" and "for the most time". Or are they a tautology here? Does "most of the time" mean "most often" or not?

What if I lived in 4 different places.

1 LA - 3 months

2 Denver -  2 months

3 LA - 3 months

4 Decatur - 4 months

5 LA - 3 months

6 NY - a year

Does my sentence convey the idea? Or should it be:

> While living in the States I lived in different places, most of the
> **times** I lived in LA, but for the most time I lived in NY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "most of the time" and "the most time" have the same meaning, and both should be applied to LA, not New York.

For New York, you would say something like:

> Most of the time I lived in LA, but I lived **the longest stretch** in New York.

or more naturally:

> Most of the time I lived in LA, but the longest stretch **was** in New York.

That said, the expressions "most of the time" and "the most time" do not mean the same thing at all. They just happen to align in this context.

"Most of the time" is an *adverb of frequency* that indicates how often something happened or how often something was true. In this case, it means "live in LA" was true more often than in any other city.

"The most time" is a *quantity*. In this case, it means the quantity of time for "live in LA" was more than in any other city.

These two expressions align in this context only because "live" is a continuous state, and we're considering the sum of the time lived in LA as a whole, rather than, say, the number of times living in LA, which is 3.

So if we're talking about something that only happens repeatedly, like the flipping of a coin, only "most of the time" makes sense because it refers to the frequency. "The most time" is a quantity of time, and it doesn't make sense to refer to the flipping of a coin in quantities of time, like "an hour".

Comment: But isn't it true that "most of the time" means the stretch of time which is more than 50% of a certain period of time?

Comment: @user1425 No. "Most of the time" is not a stretch of time. In this case, it refers to the combination of three stretches of time.

Comment: I didn't say it was a stretch of time. I meant it could refer to the total amount of time spent in one place, the amount which takes up more than 50% of all the time spent in all of the places. At least, some natives consider that "most of the time" can mean - more than 50% of a certain period of time.

Comment: You asked, '*But isn't it true that **"most of the time" means the stretch of time***...' The answer to that question is no, "most of the time" does not mean a stretch of time at all. That said, the rest of your last comment is correct -- it means more than 50% of the total combined time, without regard for any stretches of time.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different meanings of [time](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/time) with "most times" (of the various places) and "most of the time" (the longest time). In one case **occurrences** and the other **length of time**.

I suggest this version, which avoids the use of 'time' or 'times' with different meanings in the same sentence.

> While in the States I lived in different places, **most often** in LA, but for the **longest time** in NY.

Note that I have also reduced your use of the verb 'live' from four to one.